# How to implement email + password, google oauth2, githubo auth2 login, with JWT, and refresh JWT with passport in nestjs?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js, nestjs

I want to implement login with 3 strategies email, password + google + github, so far as I have implemented it, it is to have modeling in the database:

```
enum Provider {
  local
  google
  github
}

model User {
  id       String    @id @default(uuid())
  name     String?
  username String?
  email    String    @unique
  password String?
  provider Provider
}
```

In such a way that if the user logs in "locally" (email, password) he will have the password field, and if he logs in with some provider (google, github), obviously he will not have a password, then it can be ignored. But my problem is to be able to keep the user authenticated and for that I want to implement it with jsonwebtokens.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to follow some tutorials on the web? Do you have a specific problem with the implementation? Remember that SO is not a place where people write code for you. Have a look at some resources on the net and if you're stuck with a concrete issue we'll be more than happy to help.

Comment: hi, any solution to this?